# Apache Camel, DirectConsumerNotAvailableException while runing cxf on fabric8(karaf), though local runs fine

Tags: cxf, apache-camel, karaf, fabric8

I have two routs into two contexts
[first](https://github.com/soulaway/smsinfoesb/blob/master/sms-service-impl/src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint/cameJettyCxf.xml) one gets the http (jetty) request and sends it to `direct:/{{sms.endpoint.name}}`
and the [second](https://github.com/soulaway/smsinfoesb/blob/master/sms-service-impl/src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint/camelCxfJpa.xml) one gets the pojo from cxf `cxf:bean:smsCxfEndpoint`
and works with it..
The cxf endpoint looks like:

```
<camel-cxf:cxfEndpoint id="smsCxfEndpoint"
        address="camel://direct:{{sms.endpoint.name}}"
        serviceClass="ua.np.services.smsinfo.impl.SmsService"/>
```

The local runs perfect, but while it runs on container some evil appears:

Please help me ^)

```
    Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-dev-fab01-49814-1402583188376-0-2 on ExchangeId: ID-dev-fab01-49814-1402583188376-0-1). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct://smsinfo]. Exchange[Message: [Body is instance of java.io.InputStream]]


Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[jetty-to-cxf      ] [jetty-to-cxf      ] [http://0.0.0.0:8090/smsinfo?disableStreamCache=true                           ] [        65]
[jetty-to-cxf      ] [to1               ] [direct:smsinfo                                                                ] [        37]


Exchange
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exchange[
  Id                  ID-dev-fab01-49814-1402583188376-0-1
  ExchangePattern     InOut
  Headers             {Accept-Encoding=gzip,deflate, breadcrumbId=ID-dev-fab01-49814-1402583188376-0-2, CamelHttpCharacterEncoding=UTF-8, CamelHttpMethod=POST, CamelHttpPath=, CamelHttpQuery=null, CamelHttpServletRequest=(POST /smsinfo)@1969775829 org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request@756864d5, CamelHttpServletResponse=HTTP/1.1 200


, CamelHttpUri=/smsinfo, CamelHttpUrl=http://dev-fab01.np.ua:8090/smsinfo, CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0, CamelServletContextPath=/smsinfo, Connection=keep-alive, Content-Length=798, Content-Type=text/xml;charset=UTF-8, Host=dev-fab01.np.ua:8090,


SOAPAction="", User-Agent=Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)}
  BodyType            org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput
  Body                [Body is instance of java.io.InputStream]
]


Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



Stack Trace:
org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct://smsinfo]. Exchange[Message: [Body is instance of java.io.InputStream]]
  at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:47)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:110)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4]
  at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:163)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-610379 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4]
  at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelContinuationServlet.service(CamelContinuationServlet.java:151)[org.apache.camel:camel-jetty:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)[org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec:1.0]
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1496)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.MultiPartFilter.doFilter(MultiPartFilter.java:136)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
  at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelFilterWrapper.doFilter(CamelFilterWrapper.java:44)[org.apache.camel:camel-jetty:2.12.0.redhat-610379]
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
  at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
  at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)[org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-nested:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-ajp:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:8.1.14.v20131031 org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)[:1.7.0_51]
```

The deployment things presents on github in correspond pom: sms-service-impl/pom.xml, please see links above.

Thanks alot in advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code at GitHub, I don't see any `direct://smsinfo` consumer endpoint, thus the Camel error seems to be adequate. So, I guess, that your local setup is different from the one at your fabric8 instance.

By the way, I tried to build your GitHub project, but failed with following error:

> [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR]   The project ua.np.services:smsinfoesb:1.0.4-SNAPSHOT (/Developer/Workspace/Java/projects/projects-test/smsinfoesb/pom.xml) has 1 error
>   [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact ua.np.maven:npFuseParent:pom:1.0.0.redhat-610379-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 13, column 10 -> [Help 2]

Comment: Hi Peter! Thanks for reply!

smsinfo is property placeholder value:
<cm:property name="sms.endpoint.name" value="smsinfo"/>

The parent pom refer to its own anoter project. I have alredy update my github [link](https://github.com/soulaway/smsinfoesb) with parent     pom things, to be able to bild and run localy with 'clean install camel:run'
So you may try it.

Comment: also I attach the soapui project test file for easy requesting

Comment: @soulaway The `direct://smsinfo` producer endpoint (`to`) is defined but not the corresponding consumer endpoint (`from`). Thanks for upgrading the project, however the Camel Maven plugin seems not to be properly defined: "No plugin found for prefix 'camel' in the current project"

Comment: "No plugin found for prefix 'camel' in the current project" - its strange - I have successfull runs via "mvn clean install camel:run"
and the camel-maven-plugin also present in main pom.

Yes I understand that there is wrong way to consume with 'direct' and then produce to 'cxf:endpoint'.. but it works locally - that's strange!

I also have the same question in 'https://community.jboss.org/message/878039#878039'
There are some explanation what I want to get from this routes

Comment: @soulaway Your CXF endpoint is not correctly defined, see http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html. The `address` attribute should be something like `http://localhost:9001/router`

Comment: Seems there is two ways to handle my point.
1. Use router endpoint (thats cause different ports using)
2. Use JaxWs cxfbean consumer (thats will use tha same port) - http://camel.apache.org/cxf-bean-component.html
Thanks Peter for your help! I'm really pleased.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Spring, make sure you have a `@Component` annotation on your route class.

Embarrassing bug that *a friend of mine* ran into.